# Elasticsearch incorrect distance calculation and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm using elasticsearch for geo_distance filter so issue is it's distance measurement is quite off like in following query i'm filtering 2500m but it's returning me a place which is 6500m why is that so? i cross verified distance between points on google maps.

query

```
 
  "query": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sellers",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "sellers.active": true
                    }
                  }
                ],
              "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "226",
          "distance_type":"arc",
          "sellers.seller_geo": [ 31.0035008, 75.8480896]
        }
      }
              }
            },
            "inner_hits" : {
              
               "sort": [
          {
            "sellers.sale_price": "asc"
          }
        ],
        "size":1,
         "name": "hits_1"
            }
          }
        }
}
```

and result is

`````
  "took" : 47,
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "inner_hits" : {
          "hits_1" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "shopping_items",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Z0AP8VFAEO",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "sellers",
                    "offset" : 22
                  },
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "prime" : true,
                    "instant_delivery" : true,
                    "dispatch_days" : 0,
                    "active" : true,
                    "cod" : false,
                    "discount" : "21.43",
                    "list_price" : 1964.25,
                    "seller_geo" : [
                      30.998450,
                      75.848835
                    ],
                    "postal_code" : 141001,
                    "sale_price" : 1964.25,
                    "seller_id" : "A07RE66FZA"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1964.25
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}````
`````

distance between 30.998450,75.848835 and  31.0035008, 75.8480896 is 9.34km

Answer (score 0):

`[30.998450, 75.848835]` where the order is `lat, lon` is a point in Punjab, India. The other way around it'd denote a point in the Barents Sea near the Arctic Circle...

Now, the `geo_distance` [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html#_lat_lon_as_array_3), just like the `geo_point` data type parse such locations as `lon, lat`, thereby conforming to the GeoJSON standard.

In other words, your geo point was improperly indexed. You can fix it by dropping the index and reversing the coordinates. I personally like using the following notation instead

```
{
  "lat":40,
  "lon":-70
}
```

so that people don't get confused.

Comment: hey @joe thanks for your answer i'll soon reindex test and get back.